# why does this always die?

Tags: php

```
$extension = "jpg"

    if($extension != "jpg" || $extension != "gif" || $extension != "png") die("only jpg, gif, png acceptable");
```

it always seems to die().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `&&` not `||`.

Read it outloud as:

"If x doesn't equal Y OR x doesn't equal N".

Clearly, it doesn't matter what `x` equals, as long as `Y` and `N` aren't equal, the statement will always be true :)

Comment: Or `if(!($extension == 'jpg' || $extension == 'gif' || $extension == 'png'))`. Yay for De Morgan. 'Course, it's easier to overlook the `!` this way.

Comment: @Mark, De Morgan's theorem is supposed to be a way to *simplify* boolean algebra. You appear to be using it here to make it *more* complex :-)

Comment: ggg: I wouldn't worry; I'd be embarrassed to say how many times I've made this error in the past; it always helps to read out loud the statement, and even write down a few cases of it, just to check that all is well (and, obviously test :P)

Answer (score 5):

Since `$extension` cannot be `"jpg"`, `"gif"` and `"png"` at the same time, at least two of the sub-conditions are true.

And, since you're using `or (||)` instead of `and (&&)`, any true sub-condition will render the entire condition true.

You want something like:

```
if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "gif") && ($extension != "png")) {
    die ("only jpg, gif, png acceptable");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `NOT EQUAL TO` operator with a bunch of `ORs`.

```
$extension = "jpg"
if ($extension != "jpg" || 
    $extension != "gif" || 
    $extension != "png") 
    die("only jpg, gif, png acceptable");
```

You could fix this one of two ways:

- Switch all `||` to `&&`
- Simplify it be having an array of valid extensions:

---

```
$valid = array('jpg' => true, 'gif' => true, 'png' => true);
if (!isset($valid[$extension])) {
    // not a valid extension
}
```

Comment: Why not just use $valid = array('jpg','gif','png'); if (!in_array($extension, $valid) { ... } ?

Comment: @Darren - using `in_array()` requires iteration over the entire array whereas setting the array keys allows you to simply check if the key is set.  It's a simple optimization.

Comment: In the case you might want to check that the value is equal to true. That allows you to turn some extensions on and some off. And if it is unknown, it is off by default.

Comment: The in_array() solution is indeed slightly less efficient.  However, it's easier to read.  Assuming this was fairly infrequently executed code, I'd probably opt for the in_array() solution.  No sense in sacrificing readability to save a few nanoseconds.

Comment: @Frank - I never opt for slower code if I can write something faster in the same amount of time.  Also I'd argue that readability is not reduced as `!isset($valid[$extension]` jumps out at you in plain English.

Answer (score 1):

```
$extension = "jpg"

    if($extension != "jpg" && $extension != "gif" && $extension != "png") die("only jpg, gif, png acceptable");
```

This may work

Answer (score 0):

Reasons are already explained, moreover you can simply do this, with the result you expected:

```
$extension = "jpg";
if(!in_array($extension,array("jpg","gif","png"))){
    die("only jpg, gif, png acceptable");
}
```